# JFrame wont display components until 2 threads are awake

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets, network-programming

Was hoping someone could help me with this prob. I have a multi-threaded server app where the GUI JFrame will not display components until both client threads are awake. Each client is a thread created with a inner class ext Thread.

One client joins via socket connection, streams established and is then suspended until client 2 joins and same. As soon as both client threads are established and streams created, client 1 is set to suspended(false), and both client threads are awake. Only now does the JFrame display components....

The main method is also called on the EDT:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
                MorseCode_Server serverApp= new MorseCode_Server();
                serverApp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    serverApp.execute();

        }
```

Not sure what code is relevant here so I added these:
This method is the first method to be called in outer class, it sets each client/player up and suspends first thread until 2nd is ready:

```
displayMessage("Execute Called(): ");
    for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        try {
            players[i] = new Player(socket.accept(), i);//assign soc & playerNumber
            //clientIP[i] =  //get IP address for message log
            players[i].start();//JVM calls the threads run method
            displayMessage("Execute(): Player " + players[i] + " socket created in execute (OUTER CLASS)");
            //get IP address of playet[i]


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }//end for
    //player 0 is suspended once socket created until player 1 is instantiated
    //must retrun player 0 to resume state in synchronised block to allow one 
    //thread access at a time
    synchronized (players[0]) {
        players[0].setSuspended(false);
        players[0].notifyAll();//wake up threads waiting on this object
        displayMessage("Execute(): "+ players[0] + " players number notifyAll called in execute");
    }//end synchronised block
```

This is the inner class constructor for each client thread:

```
private class Player extends Thread {
    //instance varibles for each client/player
public Player(Socket accept, int i) {
        connection = accept;
        //clientIP[i] = connection.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
        playerNumber = i;
        displayMessage("Player " + playerNumber + " costructor thread inner class  called");
        //open socket streams for communication
        try {
            //objectouptstream obj wraps the low level code from getOutputStream method
            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            output.flush();
            input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            displayMessage("Player " + playerNumber + " output/input streams set up in Player inner class..END CONSTRUCTOR PLAYER");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }//end constructor inner class Player
```

Also, when i try to get the IP address of the clicent via its connection:

```
clientIP[i] = connection.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
```

I get a null pointer exception!!
Cheers in advance
C

Comment: Where is the `clientIP[i] = ...` instruction?

Comment: That's now in the player constructor,   got that sorted now i just hadn't intilised the string array holding it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't execute long running code on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). This is causing the GUI to freeze.

The code that starts your socket connections should execute in a separate Thread so it doesn't block the EDT. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. You can either create your own Thread or use a SwingWorker for this.

Comment: Cheers, ill try wrap the first execute method (which creates & suspends bew client threads) in a swingworker thread...